# Ionic geolocation - how to update position?

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation

I am new with Ionic and just fixed geolocation in my app. I can now see my position on the map but i have a problem with  position not updating on the map. I tried all possible ways and googled a lot and also read here on Stackoverflow but still nothing is working. Position is not updating. Can u please take a look at my code and tell me what i did wrong?

```
 loadMap() {

      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);


      //Red pin shows users position on the map
      var myPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        position: latLng, 
        icon: 'assets/imgs/pins/redpin.png',
        enableHighAccuracy:true
      })


      //For position update(this is a code which is not working)
        let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
        watch.subscribe((data) => {
       // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
       // data.coords.latitude
       // data.coords.longitude
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the method `watchPosition` instead of `getCurrentPosition` something like:

```
loadMap() {

  this.geolocation.watchPosition().subscribe((position) => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        icon:  'assets/imgs/pins/redpin.png',
        position: latLng,
        enableHighAccuracy:true
       });
      let message = "Current Position";
      this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);
  }, (err) => {console.log(err);} );
}
```